# TypeError: argument 1 must be string or read-only character buffer, not file (in exercise 17 of Learn python the Hard)

Tags: python

```
copying from test.txt to new1_file.txt
 The input file is 8 bytes long
 Does the output file exists, True
 readyy, hit RETURN to continue, CTRL-C to abort

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "ex17a.py", line 18, in <module>
   out_file.write(indata) 
TypeError: argument 1 must be string or read-only character buffer, not file
```

This is the code that i used

```
from sys import argv

from os. path import exists

script, from_file, to_file = argv

print "copying from %s to %s" % ( from_file, to_file)

indata = open(from_file,'r')

print " The input file is %d bytes long" % len(from_file)

print " Does the output file exists, %r" %exists(to_file)
print " readyy, hit RETURN to continue, CTRL-C to abort"

raw_input()

out_file = open(to_file, 'w')
out_file.write(indata)

print " Alright, all done"

out_file.close()
indata.close()
```

Comment: Edit the question and put the code as a code block. You also need to explain how do you run the code.

Comment: I've noticed you are quite new on SO. If one of the answers below answered your question, the way this site works works, you'd "accept" the answer, more here: [What should I do when someone answers my questions?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). But only if your question really has been answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`indata` in your line `out_file.write(indata)` is a file object. To get its content call `indata.read()`.

```
out_file.write(indata.read())
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked. I really appreciate your time, and help